# What only native speakers and native writers (?) know

Tags: written-language, psycholinguistics

Even after many years, even after getting proficient in a foreign language, non-native speakers won't lose their foreign accent.

Is there an equivalent to this for non-native writers? Will be something there that indicates that a writer is foreigner? Do native writers exists at all?

Comment: The main thing is exactly the same for spoken and written language: idioms.

Comment: I think https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2114/can-ones-native-medium-of-language-be-written-rather-than-spoken-or-signed?rq=1 covers this

Comment: The presupposition is a bit dubious. With enough practice, one can well perfect his pronunciation and intonation to a degree that it's practically impossible for a normal conversant to tell whether he's a native speaker or a later learner, especially if he started learning that language early enough, generally. Of course the majority of non-native speakers who don't specifically practice do still carry accents, but that's not a 100% thing.

Comment: non-idiomatic writing